# Mututal exclusivity in C#'s nullable flow analysis for properties

Tags: c#, .net, nullable-reference-types

Is there any way to define properties to be mutually exclusive in terms of their nullability? Meaning, if property A is not null property B is and the other way around. I am thinking of something like this:

```cs
public class Model {

    [NotNullIfMemberNull(nameof(B))]
    public string? A { get; set; }

    [NotNullIfMemberNull(nameof(A))]
    public string? B { get; set; }
}
```

I am thinking of something along the lines of `MemberNotNull` or `MemberNotNullWhen`.

This would mean the following code would not produce any nullablility warnings:

```cs
public void DoSomething(Model m)
{
    if (m.A is null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.B.Length);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(m.A.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the intended use case here -- why not just check for `m.B` directly and make the code obviously correct by construction, no matter how sure you are that this "mutual exclusion" property holds in your class? Non-trivial nullability relations can be expressed with helper methods and `MemberNotNullWhen`, but that wouldn't really simplify this scenario that I can see (`[MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(B))] bool aIsNull => A is null;` -- but then you have to remember to always use that instead of just writing the obvious check).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have updated the question to better reflect what I am trying to accomplish. You are right that I could check for `m.B` directly, however then I would need an `else if` for the second null check which would leave me with an ugly third case which I am trying to avoid.
I am okay with this not being possible, I just wanted to know if I was missing something.

Comment: It isn't possible (as far as I know), but I suspect your code can do with a redesign to make the need for this go away in any case. Exactly how is unclear since you've only given various simplified scenarios. For example, `public string C => (A ?? B)!` could be used to select the non-`null` property for read purposes. Avoiding your "third case" can also be done by adding `[MemberNotNullWhen(false, nameof(A))]` to my hypothetical `AIsNull` method, as long as it's used consistently in place of direct checks (along with a `BIsNotNull` for convenience, probably).